# Google Analytics Roll-up Property Does not Equal the Sum of the Child Properties

Tags: google-analytics

**Preface**

I have three properties, A, B, and C.

A is a property for A.com and there is a filter on that views to only include hostname "A.com". It also sends rollup hits to C.

B is a property for B.com and there is a filter on that views to only include hostname "B.com". It also sends rollup hits to C.

C is the aforementioned rollup property and has a filter for hostname to only equal r"(A|B).com"

**Problem**

Some metrics in C are equal to A+B, but other metrics are C > A+B.

For example, in A, my pageviews was 2405148, and in B was 1802017, but the rollup reports  4297385 which is a difference of 90220 pageviews.

I have also done a report on pageviews in C and broken down by hostname, and the reported values do not equal the values in the properties.

I'm stumped. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -2):

I.- Please look the guides, this question is off topic or not related to the guides stablished by StackOverFlow

II.- Extracted from the Guide
As a result, the number of sessions in a Roll-Up Property does not necessarily equal the sum of all sessions in Source Properties. The following examples illustrate how sessions are merged under different circumstances.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6033415?hl=en

- Same Client ID on each Source
- Property Different Client ID on each
- Source Property The effect of Session timeout settings

Greetings